# Visual Studio 2008 - Stuck while running, says "unable to break execution" when I try to debug

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm running a C# program on Visual Studio 2008
It freezes at some point, and when I try to pause for debugging, VS2008 freezes also.
when I close the program console window it pops up a "unable to break execution" message box.
When could be the cause of this?

Thanks
Roey

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when I try to debug a .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 project with "start external program" and the program automatically loads v4.0.  You can easily add an app.exe.config file for the external program with the SupportedRuntime specified:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" /> 
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Note that "v2.0.50727" is appropriate for 2.0, 3.0 & 3.5 regardless of service pack.

Comment: This resolves the issue for me when creating extensions and add-ins for ESRI ArcMap. You can either edit the ArcMap.exe.config file to use the appropriate version #, or you can delete it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell without some more info.

A few things to try:

1. Try using [ADPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) to get some richer information about the hang.
2. Try running detached and then attaching.
3. Try running detached and then attach from windbg.
4. Try disabling all your VS plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem running VC 6.
Using windbg didn't help as it also got hanged?!
Eventually I used kd (kernel debugger). Then when the machine hanged, KD immediately reported some driver (a backup tool) had an issue. Disabling that driver got the strange hang issue resolved.

Tal.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a very similiar issue, using Debug -> Delete all breakpoints solved the issue (breakpoints sometimes go rogue unfortunately).